How to resolve "Bundle Version Must Be Higher" error when uploading React Native Expo app to Transporter?
I have a React Native app built with Expo that I want to publish to iOS TestFlight. I’ve successfully built a previous version and submitted it, which is visible in the Apple Developer portal.
However, when I try to upload a new build using Transporter, I encounter the following error:
The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used (-19232)
The bundle version must be higher than the previously uploaded version: ‘1.1.2’. (ID: 95a62cc8-bc9d-4544-a15d-5797df75bb0a)

I have attempted to increase the version number multiple times, but the error persists.
How can I resolve this issue and successfully upload my new build to TestFlight?

Add the following to your app.config.js / app.json
    ios: {
      buildNumber: 2,
      bundleIdentifier: "com.xoxo.xoxo",
      infoPlist: {
        CFBundleShortVersionString: 1.1.2,
        CFBundleVersion: 2,
      },
    },

The buildnumber has to be updated every build or else Google Play Console & Appstore Connect will see it as the same build.
IF an ios folder is present, go to the info.plist file and check if the following items are present
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.1.2</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2</string>

